# Emit skipped when parsing config typescript files

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-config

I have a problem with the node-config library while using typescript.

My config folder is as follows: 
[image]

However after I run tsc and try to start my app from it's entry point (app.js) I get the following error:
`Error: Cannot parse config file: '..../config/development.ts': TypeError: config/development.ts: Emit skipped`
When deleting the typescript files from that folder and keeping only the .js files it works. Anybody has an idea how I can solve this?


This is how my tsconfig looks:

```
 "target": "es6" 
 "module": "commonjs"
 "strict": true
 "esModuleInterop": true
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For whoever sees this in the future, the issue was indeed in the ts-node library

Comment: And how would you resolve this issue??

Comment: Put the config folder inside of the src folder

Comment: Update on the original post: nowadays I just use the config folder in parallel to src but the files inside of the config folder i keep .js, I don't really need type checking there so it's kinda fine, hopefully the issue in ts-node will be resolved soon.

Comment: Update on the update, apparently this fixes the issue in ts-node above 0.10
https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/693#issuecomment-889531876

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript files outside of the project folder will produce an Emit skipped error. I can't tell if this is your issue because '..../config/' could be inside or outside the project.  In my case, moving my configuration folder into my project worked around the bug.  Blechy.

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/693

Answer (score 2):

I got this error for having an `index.js` file next to an `index.ts` file. I somehow rendered my TS to my rootDir source folder.

Terminal grab of error and fix:

```
> node --loader ts-node/esm src/index.ts

/sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:944
          throw new TypeError(`${relative(cwd, fileName)}: Emit skipped`);
                ^
TypeError: src/services/index.js: Emit skipped
    at getOutput (/sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:944:17)
    at Object.compile (/sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1243:30)
    at /sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:282:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/dist/esm.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/dist/esm.js:4:12)
    at transformSource (/sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/dist/esm.js:127:16)
    at /sandbox/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:197:51
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
sandbox@sse-sandbox-4stfq:/sandbox$ ls src/services/
index.js  index.ts  user
sandbox@sse-sandbox-4stfq:/sandbox$ rm src/services/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

`"allowJS": true` works for me.

The forcing to chage the settings is not good, but this error has been admitted as bug.
https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/693

Answer (score 0):

If nothing worked for you try updating `ts-node` to `10.7`. It worked for me.

```
"ts-node": "^10.7.0",
```